# Processing text coming off a serial line in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, serial-port

I've got an embedded device running Linux that I can communicate with via RS232. I'm attempting to programmatically control it from within an existing .NET application, so I've been fooling around with the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class. I'm reading data off the port right now by using the `SerialPortDataRecieved` event handler and checking for the amount of bytes to read, then passing in a `byte[]` of that size, THEN shoving that `byte[]` into a `Queue<byte[]>` for further processing, like this:

```
public class SerialTalk{
SerialPort s;    
Queue<byte[]> RecQueue=new Queue<byte[]>;
//...bunch of irrelevant stuff here (ctors etc)
   private void DataReceivedHandler(Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
        byte[] recv;
        lock (s_lock)
        {
            int bytes = s.BytesToRead;
            recv = new byte[bytes];
            s.Read(recv, 0, bytes);
        }

        Console.Write(recv);
        lock (RecQueue)
        {
            RecQueue.Enqueue(recv);
        }
   }
}
```

Another thread then reads from that queue to perform processing, printing to the terminal, etc. This has been working great for printing, but I want to be able to regex the data I'm retrieving. The problem is, the amount of bytes returned by the `SerialPort` is unpredictable and completely unaware of what information it is sending, so the chunks of data I'm getting are, generally, fragments of lines.

What I'm looking for is a simple, performant, multithreaded way to go from line fragment `byte[]` to `string`s that are organized neatly according to lines. One idea I had was to have another thread looping infinitely that would Dequeue `byte[]`s from the queue, turn them into `string`s, append them to a `StringBuilder`, then split the `string` returned from `StringBuilder.ToString()` along the `newlines`, the take the LAST string and use it to construct a new `StringBuilder` for the next time around, then enqueue all the other strings into a `Queue<string>` -- this way, fragments would get put back together... but this won't work in the most important case of all, which is when I'm waiting to find the shell prompt, since that string won't ever get put into the second queue.

Ideas?

Comment: Is the data coming back ASCII?

Comment: yes, I've been using `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` to convert from `byte[]` to string. This isn't where my problem lies, however.

Comment: Sure, just asking as it is relevant to any solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a small state machine.  For each byte received, if it's not a newline, add it to the 'current string' data.

If it is a newline, fire the 'new-data'; event.

If you detect that the 'current string' is equal to the expected 'shell prompt', fire the 'new-data' event.

Perform that processing for each byte received in turn.  That doesn't stop you reading all available bytes from the port at once, of course.

Comment: One problem with this is that although the kernel is Linux, I often have to talk to the bootloader which is some god-knows-what contraption that uses "\r\n" newlines. I was hoping to have a solution that operated "string-wise" rather than "byte-wise" for this reason.

Comment: It will always have to be byte-wise: serial port data comes in as a series of bytes.  To combat that problem, either 1) ignore all '\r' characters, drop them completely, or 2) trim off any '\r' from the current string before firing the event (it will still end in '\n', of course).  Or, you can try to maintain state and guess whether \r or \r\n is expected, and wait for the one you want.  I do not recommend that option.  (Or if it's always \r\n, add another state to the state machine: a flag to indicate the last character was a '\r'.  If flag is set and you have a '\n', you have your newline)

Comment: I know that serial ports are inherently byte-wise -- what I meant was that I'd prefer a solution that operated on the `byte[]`s after I've already read them from the `SerialPort`. I experimented previously with reading off the `SerialPort` byte by byte rather than letting it fill my buffer for me and ran into dropped data, hanging, etc. Maybe I was just doing it wrong. I read on some other QA site that this method was the preferred method for interacting with the `SerialPort` class. I'm new to .NET: is this not the case?

Comment: You needn't read it from the port byte-by-byte, and that is not the preferred option.  (That is not what I have suggested)  However, you should process the bytes one at a time (i.e. loop through them).  Read as much as you can from the port at a type, within reason (suggest a buffer of a few kilobytes).

Answer (score 0):

I would Just buffer characters in DataReceivedHandler until you detected a newline and then Queue the chars before the newline (\r\n) as a string and keep the remaining chars in the buffer until the next newline. Usually for \r\n situations I always scrub the \r's and only interpret the \n's.

Here's a quick mod to your source for illustration.

```
public class SerialTalk{
SerialPort s;    
Queue<string> RecQueue=new Queue<string>();
//...bunch of irrelevant stuff here (ctors etc)
string innerBuffer = ""; //a buffer we keep in between DataReceiveHandlers for the portion of text not newlined yet
private void DataReceivedHandler(Object sender, object e)
{
    byte[] recv;

    lock (s_lock)
    {
        int bytes = s.BytesToRead;
        recv = new byte[bytes];
        s.Read(recv, 0, bytes);
    }
    innerBuffer += System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(recv).Replace("\r\n","\n"); //could be enhanced using stringbuilder.
    string[] lines = innerBuffer.Split('\n'); 
    innerBuffer = lines[lines.Length-1];  //always keep the portion after the last newline in the buffer
    Console.Write(recv);
    lock (RecQueue)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<innerBuffer.Length-2;x++) //-2 here instead of -1 as you don't want to send the remainder of the inner buffer until the next newline
            RecQueue.Enqueue(lines[x]);
    }
}
}
```

*should be noted that converting to utf-8 from your byte array may cause additional issues. If you still want to send it as a byte[] into the Queue, you can still keep a buffer locally like the innerBuffer string does, but \r\n delineation marks won't be quite as trivial to find as Split, although still not a big deal.

Comment: DataRecievedHandler locks the serial port, and sitting waiting for the next newline would cause a deadlock if a newline never arrives (as in when the shell prompt appears, i.e. my whole motivation for doing this in the first place)

Comment: That's not what I mean. I will provide a pseudocode snippit to better illustrate

Comment: Oh, yes. Thats the solution I considered at the end of the original post, just using a `string` instead of a `StringBuilder`. it doesn't address the issue I raised in the original post -- since it doesn't send strings into the received queue until it sees a newline, it will never send the shell prompt to the received queue. Also, since yours uses a string and not a `StringBuilder` it will perform worse

Comment: Ok, I interpreted your end statements as an ADDITIONAL process, instead of just doing it during catching the event. But I see what you mean regarding it not sending partial strings, which is aparently exactly what you do and don't want ;)